# Is there a Queue (PriorityQueue) implementation which is also a Set?

Tags: java, queue, set, priority-queue

I'm looking for a [PriorityQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) implementation which is also a [Set](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

The `compareTo` implementation if its elements must not have the requirement to be consistent with the implementation of `equals`.

Is there somewhere such a implementation for java?

**Update:** I implemented it now using a SortedSet as the internal collection. So I only had to implement the missing methods to satisfy the queue interface. I also forgot to mention that it also had to be a bounded queue, so it features a capacity and discards the last element of the set if capacity is reached.

Answer (score 7):

If it's sufficient to have a queue with a 'Set-like' behaviour, iaw you just don't want to accept duplicate entries, then I think, an easy solution could be to subclass `PriorityQueue` and override the `add()`, `addAll()` and `offer()` methods like:

```
@Override
public boolean offer(E e) {
  if (contains(e)) {
    return false; 
  } else {
    return super.offer(e);
  }
}
```

BTW - `add()` calls `offer()` internally, so maybe it's even enough to just override the `offer()` method and do the check there.

Comment: Thats one possibility I thought of. I just thought that somebody maybe already implemented such a collection.

Answer (score 3):

[`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is a set that provides an ordered iterator. It implements the [`SortedSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) interface, which guarantees that the iterator returned by the `iterator` method will return the set's elements in ascending order as determined either by their natural ordering (through `Comparable`), or as determined by a comparator given to the set at its creation.

Answer (score 1):

Well the `PriorityQueue` is going to itself be dependent on the `Comparitor` or the natural ordering of the items for its sorting, likewise the `Set` would be dependent on the natural ordering or the `Comparitor` function so no I don't think one exists as part of the default Java install...

But you could probably create one pretty easily if speed isn't a worry by simply implementing the interfaces you want, and using their natural backings, etc... aka

```
MyQueueSet extends PriorityQueue implements Set {
    HashSet set;
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately Java's java.util.* data-set classes aren't always the easiest to extend without rewriting chunks of their code.

The `PriorityQueue` backing is a heap sorted list of elements, so inserting a new element and then doing a `contains(e)` test will an O(n) search because sorting is based on the queuing, *not* on the data value, if you include a `HashSet` to support the `Set` functionality though, you can improve your lookup time a lot at the expense of maintaining the dataset references twice (remember that Java is pass-by-value and all objects live on the heap). This should improve performance of a large set.

Comment: but the objects are not shared between queue and set... they are completely unrelated... this is a sort of (wrong) multiple inheritance?

Comment: @dfa The objects are shared between the queue and the set... its just their references get stored in two sets... My suggestion is the exact same one as @Andreas_D - its a very common solution used in Java's Collections work. If Java's Collections where easier to extend and create your own it wouldn't be so hackish...

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. A priority queue is already sorted, so you would need only a normal set. Further I think that in my case the overhead for having two collections would be to high, my objects are relatively small, but I have a lot of them.

Comment: @Mauli The PriorityQueue is a heap sorted list, I'm pretty sure the Set backing is either a Hash or Red & Black Tree backing depending on which implementation you pick, so you can either have O(n) time contains search or a O(log n) or O(1) hash lookup so you're right in that reguard I'll update the answer...

Answer (score 0):

PriorityQueue is an AbstractCollection - this has an almost identical interface to a Set.  I'm sure it would be easy to make a wrapper that converts a PriorityQueue to a Set.  You could keep a side hash table of inserted elements to avoid duplicates, if you really need to enforce that.

I don't think PriorityQueue requires compareTo to be consistent with equals.  PriorityQueue doesn't use equals at all (except for its inherited AbstractCollection operations?).

Comment: no, the PriorityQueue doesn't have the consistency constraints, but a sorted set does. And I really doen't want to have two collections holding the same elements.