# Can the stl c++ priority queue be used with stl set?

Tags: c++, stl, set, priority-queue

My question is identical to [Is there a Queue (PriorityQueue) implementation which is also a Set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869036/is-there-a-queue-priorityqueue-implementation-which-is-also-a-set) except that this one is about c++ and stl.

Is it possible to use the stl priority queue with the stl set as the container class? If not, is there an alternative container class that I can use with the priority queue to also make it a set?

Comment: Instead of asking how to jam a square peg into a round hole, can you say what it is that you want to accomplish? (Other than breaking off the corners of the peg `<g>`)

Comment: Why do you want to make it a set? Do you want unique membership?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, I want unique membership.

Comment: To be a bit more constructive: the container adaptor `queue` requires a container type that allows pushing new elements at its back and popping elements from its front. `std::set` doesn't to that; it has its own notion of the order that its elements should be in, so doesn't support pushing and popping.

Comment: @Peter You’re talking about `queue` while the OP is talking about a *priority queue* (which doesn’t exist as a data structure class in the STL, although it’s implemented as a set of algorithms).

Comment: The Sequence requirement for the std::priority_queue requires a lot more than just push and pop. owagh you should read up on the container requirements themselves. You can do this, but it will require you rolling a container that establishes the additional constraints you're placing (uniqueness), as I'm not aware of a stock std container that fulfills everything required + uniqueness (which I assume you'd be enforcing by throwing an exception on violation).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - the container adaptor `std::priority_queue` has been part of the C++ standard since forever; it's defined in the same header as `queue`. There are also algorithms to implement and manage a heap, which can be used as a priority queue, but has a broader interface.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I was, indeed, talking about `queue`, as in "Queue (Priority Queue)" in the question; it responds to the first alternative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The specification of `std::priority_queue` does not allow "unique membership". If you want unique membership in your priority queues, then *you don't want `std::priority_queue`*.

If you want a priority queue implementation with unique membership, then `std::set` *already does that*, because it keeps its members in sorted order.

Comment: I didn't realise that since set is already in sorted order, it already *is* a priority queue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient implementation possible, but you could do something like this. (Note I'm not trying to meet the exact interface of std::priority_queue here, not interested in changing the comparison operator, or the underlying container, or the std::set allocator).

Rather than throwing when a duplicate is pushed, this implementation just pretends the push was successful.

```
template<class T>
class UniquePriorityQueue
{
public:
    typedef typename std::priority_queue<T>::size_type size_type;

    void push(const T& v)
    {
        auto i = membership_.insert(v);
        if(i.second)
        {
            queue_.push(v);
        }
    }

    void pop(void)
    {
        membership_.erase(queue_.top());
        queue_.pop();
    }

    const T& top() const
    {
        return queue_.top();
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return queue_.empty();
    }

    size_type size() const 
    {
        return queue_.size();
    }

private:
    std::priority_queue<T> queue_;
    std::set<T> membership_;
};
```

A main that drives the functions that are implemented...

```
int main()
{
    UniquePriorityQueue<int> q;
    q.push(1);
    q.push(1);
    q.push(8);
    q.push(4);
    q.push(2);
    q.push(8);
    q.push(5);
    q.push(7);

    assert(q.size() == 6);
    assert(q.top() == 8);
    q.pop();

    assert(q.top() == 7);
    q.pop();

    assert(q.top() == 5);
    q.pop();

    assert(q.top() == 4);
    q.pop();

    assert(q.top() == 2);
    q.pop();

    assert(q.top() == 1);
    q.pop();

    assert(q.empty());  
}
```